# powershell netsh importing xml profiles

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, netsh

I have the following script that exports all of the endusers wifi profiles.

```
netsh wlan export profile folder="\\server\%username%\Wireless"
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -File wireless_backup.ps1
```

then the profile names are put into a .CSV using "wireless_backup.ps1". Here is wireless_backup.ps1.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\server\$env:username\Wireless" | Select Name | Export-CSV -path '\\server\$env:username\Wireless'
```

All of the above works fine.... Restoring these profiles onto another PC is where I am getting stuck. Here is the restoration script.

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -File wireless_restore.ps1
```

the wireless_restore.ps1 contains this bit of code.

```
$ProfileList=IMPORT-CSV \\server\$env:username\Wireless\wireless.csv

FOREACH ($Profile in $ProfileList) {
netsh wlan add profile filename= $Profile.name
}
```

My expectation was that the Wifi profiles would automatically add themselves to the PC. I'm not sure where I went wrong. Please help!

**update**
My boss did not want to use MS User State Migration for some reason, but we are doing mass re-imaging. I needed a way to easily make backups of all the following: user profile data, chrome bookmarks, itunes backups, outlook pst files, printers, wireless profiles, outlook auto-complete, wallpaper and a few other things.

here is the backup script I came up with

```
REM FORCE OUTLOOK CLOSED, PST FILES WILL NOT BACKUP IF IN USE
cscript "\\server\outlook.vbs"

REM BACKUP USERS PROFILE
xcopy "%userprofile%" "\\server\%username%\%username%" /e /y /i

REM BACKUP SIGNATURES
xcopy "%appdata%\microsoft\signatures" "\\server\%username%\Signatures" /e /y /i

REM BACKUP PINNED TASKBAR ITEMS
xcopy "%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar" "\\server\%username%\TaskBar" /e /y /i

REM BACKUP OUTLOOK ARCHIVES PST OUTLOOK MUST BE CLOSED
xcopy "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*.pst" "\\server\%username%\Outlook" /y /i

REM BACKUP CHROME BOOKMARKS
xcopy "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" "\\server\%username%\Chrome" /e /y /i

REM BACKUP iTUNES MOBILE BACKUPS
xcopy "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync" "\\server\%username%\MobileSync" /e /y /i

REM BACKUP ADVANCED COLOR SETTINGS
REG EXPORT "HKCU\Control Panel\Colors" "\\server\%username%\Wallpaper\Colors1.reg" /y

REM BACKUP ADVANCED COLOR SETTINGS
REG EXPORT "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors" "\\server\%username%\Wallpaper\Colors2.reg" /y

REM BACKUP DESKTOP BG SETTINGS
REG EXPORT "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" "\\server\%username%\Wallpaper\WindowMetrics_Backup.reg" /y

REM START WALLPAPER BACKUP SCRIPT
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "wallpaper.ps1"

    wallpaper.ps1 looks like this
    $wallpaper = (Get-ItemProperty 'hkcu:\control panel\desktop\' -Name Wallpaper).Wallpaper
    xcopy $wallpaper "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\$env:username\Wallpaper\"

REM EXPORTS ALL CURRENTLY INSTALLED PRINTERS TO CSV
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -File "\\itmdtren\z$\backup scripts\print_backup.ps1"

    printer_backup.ps1 looks like this
    Get-WMIObject -class Win32_Printer -computer $env:computername | Select Name | Export-CSV

REM EXPORT ALL XML WLAN PROFILES TO BACKUP
netsh wlan export profile folder="\\itmdtren\z$\backup\%username%\Wireless"

REM EXPORTS NAMES OF ALL WLAN PROFILES TO CSV
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -File "\\itmdtren\z$\backup scripts\wireless_backup.ps1"

    wireless_backup.ps1 looks like this
    Get-ChildItem "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\$env:username\Wireless" | Select Name | Export-CSV -path '\\itmdtren\z$\backup\$env:username\Wireless\wireless.csv'
```

After I image a computer, I logon as the user and run the following script. This is where your answers helped! As you can see the wifi profile export script is a modified version of the printer backup script shown above.

```
REM FORCE OUTLOOK CLOSED
cscript "\\itmdtren\z$\backup scripts\outlook.vbs"

REM RESTORE USERS PROFILE
xcopy "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\%username%\%username%" "%userprofile%" /e /y /i

REM RESTORE SIGNATURES
xcopy "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\%username%\Signatures" "%appdata%\microsoft\signatures" /e /y /i

REM THIS LINE NOT USED RESTORE TASKBAR
REM xcopy "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\%username%\TaskBar" "%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar" /e /y /i

REM RESTORE OUTLOOK DATA FILES PST
xcopy "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\%username%\Outlook\*.pst" "C:\Users\%username%\Documents\Outlook Files" /y /i

REM RESTORE USER DEFAULT CHROME BOOKMARKS/SETTINGS
xcopy "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\%username%\Chrome" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" /e /y /i

REM RESTORE ITUENS BACKUPS
xcopy "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\%username%\MobileSync" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync" /e /y /i

REM RESTORE ADVANCED DISPLAY SETTINGS
REG import "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\%username%\Wallpaper\Colors1.reg"
REG import "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\%username%\Wallpaper\Colors2.reg"
REG import "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\%username%\Wallpaper\WindowMetrics_Backup.reg"

REM wallpaperchanger.exe IS A COMMANDLINE UTILITY THAT RANDOMLY SELECTS A IMAGE FROM A FOLDER, CONVERTS TO BMP, COPIES TO USER PROFILE AND SETS BACKGROUD
"\\itmdtren\z$\backup scripts\WallpaperChanger.exe" "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\%username%\Wallpaper" 2 "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes"

REM FORCE UPDATE USER SYSTEM PARAMETERS
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters

REM RESTORE PRINTERS FROM CSV
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -File "\\itmdtren\z$\backup scripts\print_restore.ps1"

    print_restore.ps1 looks like this
    $PrinterList=IMPORT-CSV \\itmdtren\z$\backup\$env:username\Printers\printer_export.csv

    FOREACH ($Printer in $PrinterList) {
    Start-Sleep -s 10
    Invoke-Expression 'rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /q /n $($Printer.Name)'
    }

REM RESTORE XML WLAN PROFILES FROM CSV
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -File "\\itmdtren\z$\backup scripts\wireless_restore.ps1"

    wireless_restore.ps1 looks like this
    $ProfileList=IMPORT-CSV \\itmdtren\z$\backup\$env:username\Wireless\wireless.csv

    FOREACH ($Profile in $ProfileList) {
    $fullname = Join-Path "\\itmdtren\z$\backup\$env:username\Wireless" $profile.name
    netsh wlan add profile filename= $fullname
    }
```

This is what the user backup looks like after the script completes
[image]

as you can see all the XML wireless profiles did indeed get exported and the powershell script put the names of all these files in a csv.
[image]

here is what the csv looks like

[image]

the powershell script will not work for local printers, but we can use printbrm.exe to back those up with the drivers. it did work for all the network printers just fine.
[image]

The restoration script puts all this back onto the newly imaged PC without any problems and I owe it all to the members of Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Profile.Name is not enough, you should provide the full unc path,

try this

```
FOREACH ($Profile in $ProfileList) {
$fullname = Join-Path "\\server\$env:username\Wireless" $profile.name
netsh wlan add profile filename= $fullname
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code exactly as shown and it worked!! Please see the update in my original post!!

Answer (score 0):

I still have to test but I think I'm with Avshalom on this one with what the source of the issue is. Name is just a file name and extension. It is not the full file path which is what you should be using to get consistent results. It is possible that if the current directory in your PowerShell session was `\\server\%username%\Wireless` that you *might* not have an issue.

Without testing as I do not have a wireless profile on this computer I suggest that you do away with the CSV all together since you only want the one thing anyway. I don't know if this was a typo but you export is not really the path you want. In your restore script you use `\\server\$env:username\Wireless\wireless.txt` but in your backup script we see `\\server\$env:username\Wireless`. Assuming you have the permissions you would see a file call "Wireless" under `\\server\$env:username`.

wireless_backup.ps1

```
Get-ChildItem "\\server\$env:username\Wireless" | Select-Object -Expand FullName | Set-Content -path '\\server\$env:username\Wireless\wireless.txt'
```

wireless_restore.ps1

```
$ProfileList=Get-Content \\server\$env:username\Wireless\wireless.txt

FOREACH ($Profile in $ProfileList) {
    netsh wlan add profile filename=$Profile
}
```

FYI I don't know ( but am in the process of looking up) if this is a suitable way to export wireless profiles.

Comment: I wish I could mark both answers as right!! Please see the update in my original post!!